# React module system vs Express module system

Tags: reactjs, express, npm, es6-modules, commonjs

When using react, we import the library in the following manner
`import React from 'react'`

In express, we use
`const app = require('express')`

In their github source code, both of them uses module.exports which indicates they are using commonJS. But I read on the internet that react uses ES6 Modules and not commonJS. I am actually confused if that's the case, then why are they using module.exports in the source code

Also, when I use `import react from 'react'` instead of `import React from 'react'`, my app crashes. I would like to know what actually `react` exports. I checked out their source code but didn't find any default named export